# How to calculate a function for corresponding values of three vectors, then for each values of these, for each value of a fourth

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a calculation of Bayesian probability. Input variables are:

```
L<-c(1,1,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5)
D<-c(1,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0)
N<-c(1:10)
n<-cumsum(D)
i<-c(1:10)
L1<-L+1
f1 <- function(i,L1) if(i < L1) 1 else if(i == L1) i else L1:i
T<-Map(f1,i,L1)
```

Where the latter variable *T* represents a list of numeric vectors, each associated with a value of *i*. I want to run the following equation for all corresponding values of *i*,*L* and *n* but for each of these I want to run it for all values of *T*.

```
PDEi<-ifelse((L+1)>i,PDEi<-0,PDEi<-choose((L-1),(n-1))/choose((T-1),n))
```

So when i=9, L=5, n=4, I want to know the sum of this equation for all values of T, where T is the vector (6, 7, 8, 9) when i=9. No idea how to do this and online research has not helped.

Desired output is a matrix showing the output value of the equation for each value of T, for each value of the other variables. When T has only one value then there is only one row for the other values. e.g.

```
i  L  n  T  PDEit
1  1  1  1  0
2  1  1  2  1
.....
7  5  4  6  0.8
7  5  4  7  0.6666667
8  5  4  6  0.8
8  5  4  7  0.6666667
8  5  4  8  0.5714286
```

There will be four values of T for i=9 and 5 values of T for i=10.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @akrun Please see edits above. Thanks.